# Disabling loading of images in JavaFX WebEngine

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I've searched everywhere but found no way to disable loading of images by Java WebEngine.

#### Research done:

I found some ideas, such as using `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()` to use my own `URLStreamHandler`, and having that analyze the URL to only return `URLConnection`s for URL's that don't end in .jpg .png etc. BUt that has many problems: Sometimes the image url doesn't end in .jpg, if it's a dynamic image, such as a captcha. So how can I disable automatic image loading from WebEngine?

Comment: Consider moving 'Research done:' to an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm no JSoup expert but it should be easy enough to do something like this.

```
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class NoImg extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL("http://www.google.com"), 5000);
        doc.select("img").stream().forEach((element) -> {
            element.remove();
        });
        we.loadContent(doc.outerHtml());
        Scene scene = new Scene(wv, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

It seems to work fine.  You need the [jsoup.jar](http://jsoup.org/download%20%22)

Comment: yes but sometimes the page requires a lot of javascript when manipulating the DOM, for example if I select a certain combobox a certain textfield is enabled in the dom through the page javascript, so using the WebEngine.load() is needed because it handles all javascript processing when manipulating the dom, filling out forms etc, whereas jsoup I don't think does that, it only parses the base html into dom, w/out future js processing when manipulating the dom.
Also, images are sometimes inserted w/out the img tag, for example using the style background-image.